# Primefaces datatable: partial processing on Form and row select datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a primefaces form that have set of inputtext , datatable and finally to commandbutton.
First CommandButton "Full Submit" is used to submit all forms inputs to backbean , Second Commandbutton " Partial Submit" is used to processes certain inputs and add record to datattable " itemDT"
On click on " Partial Submit", ajax request form datatable on rowselect ,pass null SelectEvent to method
On click on " Full Submit" ,ajax request form datatable on rowselect ,pass  not null SelectEvent to method

```
<h:form id="generalForm">
<p:inputText label="full_submit_input_one" id="inpt1"/>
<p:inputText label="full_submit_input_two" id="inpt2"/>

<h:panelGrid columns="4" id="partial_submit_Panel">
    <p:inputText label="partial_submit_input_one" id="inpt3"/>
    <p:inputText label="partial_submit_input_two" id="inpt4"/>
</h:panelGrid>

<p:dataTable id="itemDT" var="item"  value="#{itemView.items}" selectionMode="multiple"
        selection="#{itemView.selectedItems}" 
        rowKey="#{fee.Id}">
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
            listener="#{dtFeesView.onRowSelect}" />
    <p:column headerText="Input three">
        <h:outputText value="#{fee.inpt3}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Input four">
        <h:outputText value="#{fee.inpt4}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

<p:commandButton value="Full Submit"  actionListener="#{itemView.add}"/>
<p:commandButton value="Partial Submit"  actionListener="#{itemView.insertRecord}" process=":generalForm:partial_submit_Panel"/>
```

```
@ManagedBean(name="itemView")
@ViewScoped
public class ItemView{
    private ItemModel selectedItems[];
    // getters and setters for selectedItems
    private List<ItemModel> items;
    // getters and setters for items

    public void add(){
        // add item to i.e database
    }

    public void insertRecord(){
        // add itemModels  to items list 
    }
    public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        ItemModel model =(ItemModel)event.getObject();
        // model is null in case of process with value :generalForm:partial_submit_Panel
        //model is not null in case of process with value generalForm "submit full form"
    }
}
```

Please help.
thanks

Comment: There is nothing abnormal. The button labelled `Partial Submit` processes `process=":generalForm:partial_submit_Panel"` which an `<h:panelGrid>` and the data table is excluded from being processed. What are you trying to do? If this is targeted to basic CRUD operations, there are fancy ways to achieve this. You have to just look a little at the showcase.

Comment: thanks Tiny for reply .I want to add some records to datatable which i can edit/delete these records before i submit the full form.